# Haskell - causing immediate termination of list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to write a function that efficiently tells me when
items in a list are divisible or not by all items in a range. The problem is, I don't know to stop the list comprehension immediately when a false is encountered.

```
allDivisByRng n start stop =
  [n `mod` x == 0 | x <- [start, start+1 .. stop]]
```

I have tried `takeWhile` but can't get that to do what I want. Please advise.

```
allDivisByRng n start stop =
  takeWhile( == True )     [ n  `mod`  x == 0 | x <- [start, start+1.. stop] ]
```

When I run `allDivisByRng 10 2 4` I  get a list of trues

Some other sample runs

```
*Main> allDivisByRng 12 2 10
[True,True,True]
*Main> allDivisByRng 12 2 150
[True,True,True]
-- I want this to return false
*Main> allDivisByRng 2520 2 10
[True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]
-- I want this to return True
```

I have also tried searching for `False`

```
allDivisByRng n start stop =
   takeWhile( == False )     [ n  `mod`  x == 0 | x <- [start, start+1.. stop] ]

*Main> allDivisByRng 10 2 3
[]
-- want false to be returned
*Main> allDivisByRng 10 2 10
[]
-- want false to be returned
*Main> allDivisByRng 2520 2 10
[]
-- want true to be returned
*Main> allDivisByRng 12 2 10
[]
-- want false to be returned
```

Comment: Haskell is a lazy language, meaning that values are computed only when they're requested. There is more or less no notion of "stop computation". Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How exactly are you able to observe the behavior? `takeWhile` should be sufficient, what exactly have you tried and what exactly did not work?

Comment: I have tried: allDivisByRng n start stop =
   takeWhile( == True )     [ n  `mod`  x == 0 | x <- [start, start+1.. stop] ]

Comment: Please add that to the question itself and, most importantly, specify how do you run the function, what result do you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: If you just use `and :: [Bool] -> Bool`, computation should be automatically stopped when a `False` is encountered, since Haskell is lazy. You don't need to worry about this problem if you just do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all),

```
all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
```

allows you to check whether all elements of a foldable structure satisfy a certain condition. In your case,

```
allDivisByRng n start stop = all ((== 0) . (mod n)) [start..stop]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of "stopping a list comprehension" in Haskell. By default, evaluation is [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). This means values aren't really computed until they are actually needed.

This allows us to work with infinite data structures:

```
take 10 [1..]
--> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Or with structures that have invalid values in them:

```
take 1 ["It works!", error "Exception thrown"]
--> "It works!"
```

So we just need to process the list to a function that reduces the list of booleans to a single bool.

[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BBool%5D+-%3E+Bool) is a nifty little tool to search for functions that match a given type signature. I'd recommend you get acquainted with it, because more often that not you'll find exactly what you're looking for.

In this case, searching for `[Bool] -> Bool` (a function that reduces a list of booleans to a single bool) gives us the following function defined in the Prelude (no imports needed):

```
and :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool
```

See if you can apply it to get what you want!

There happens to be another function that is a bit closed to what we want: test if all elements in a list satisfy a predicate. With this "[`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all)" fuction, we can rewrite your function in a very legible way (imo):

```
allDivisByRng n start stop =
    all (n `isDividedBy`) [start .. stop]
    where
        n `isDividedBy` x  =  n `mod` x == 0
```